# DBA group in Linux

Tags: oracle, unix

When we need to install Oracle database in Linux then the user should be in dba group. What is this group and why the user should be in this group for installing Oracle database. What happens if the user does not belong to this group? Please help me in understanding this.

Comment: This group is the owner of the Oracle software installation and also the owner of the datafiles, redo logs and other files Oracle uses. The Oracle Server should have read/write access to these files and dirs. This group is also used to authenticate users with SYSDBA privilege, so that they log in without providing password from command line. You will also want to create directories and give `dba` group read/write access to them so that Oracle can read from and write to these directories when you use Data Pump, SQL*Loader, `BFILE`s etc.

Comment: Good question, I thought the documentation would say more on this but I couldn't easily find the relevant links. Can someone add them to an answer here?

Comment: Some information is here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24321/pre_install.htm#BABHHEJD

Comment: @YasirA no, at  least on my installation  the group of the oracle software is not the dba group

Answer (score 1):

The dba group name is registered in the oracle binary and can be verified using

```
grep SS_DBA_GRP $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/config.c
```

Members of this local defined group are normally dba's can connect locally to the database using os authentication and use their sysdba role doing so.
This prevents having to work using the software owner's account(often "oracle")
Using this local os authentication is a bit more secure than using a password because a password can also be using from any other machine.

It is the magic making `"sqlplus / as sysdba"` work.

Requirements are that ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID are set.